# Div with height as rest blank space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 2 divs on my 100% screen. One of them is aligned to bottom and has different heights on different devices. i need to set the height of the second div to be equal to the remaining space of the page and into this div i added an `img` that is also aligned to bottom of its own div. I am using `flexbox` but my first div has height as whole `flexbox`.

I need exactly this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTbVf.jpg

here is html :

```
<div class="flexing">
    <div class="div1">
        <img class="background" src="img/asset7.png">
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
        <div class="row">
                some text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And there is my css :

```
.flexing{
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.div1{
    width: 100%;
}
.div2{
    width: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
.background {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `position:absolute` in a flexbox instead of using the flex properties available to you?

Comment: Do u want left side image and right side text?

Comment: No i need image at top div and text in lower.

Comment: @Paulie_D Because i need inner element align to bottom of that div. And second div aling on bottom of page.